# Искажения изображения в ray marching-е

Tags: графика, 3d, glsl

Я пытался написать программу, занимающуюся ray marching-ом, но в определенный момент заметил, что в некоторых местах стали появляться непонятные искажения изображения.
Код и результат его выполнения вы можете посмотреть здесь: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wdBBzt (модель можно врящать мышью). Должен рисоваться куб, из которого вырезаны 7 меньших кубов (1 в центре и по 1-му на каждой грани), но в местах выреза изображение выглядит странно. Из-за чего могли образоваться искажения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри функции `map()` Вы умножили положение, для которого ищете значение функции sdf, таким образом Вы исказили пространство в этом месте, т.е. нашли значение для другой точки

```
float d3 = sdcross(p * 3.0);
d = max(d, -d3);
```

Я бы рекомендовал не искажать пространство, а изменить функцию, которой вы вычитаете объем:

```
float sdbox2d(in vec2 p) {
    vec2 d = abs(p) - .33;  // вот тут я поменял 1 на 0.33
    return length(max(d, 0.0)) + min(max(d.x, d.y), 0.0);
}
```

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wdBBRd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Но не могли бы вы объяснить, посчему искажение пространства приводит к проблеме, а Ваше решение - нет?

Comment: ну смотрите, основа алгоритма - определить безопасное расстояние, на которое можно шагнуть вдоль луча и не пройти сквозь объект, а Вы находите это расстояние для другой точки пространства, т.е. нарушаете работу алгоритма

Comment: Осознал свою ошибку. В 34-ой строке хотел сделать, как написано тут (в конце в пунке scale), но забыл домножить. https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm      Вот тоже работающий вариант. https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wsBBRd